# Installing a Smart Switch only for automations?

Tags: wiring, switch, smart-switch

I'm replacing both of my single-pole switches in my room with newer Smart Switches from Meross. One controls my light and one controls my fan. However, I want to also replace my light with a smart light, meaning it will always have to be on in order to operate. So I am trying to make one of the smart switches operate normally (for my fan) but I want the other to only act as a button for automation so that when I physically press it button off it'll only set the brightness to 0%, and back to whatever it was on when I press it again. This means that the smart switch will always require power, but I also need to make sure the load and hot wire are always connected as well, right? Do I need to somehow jumper some cables to the switch or is this not possible at all?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use the Meross devices specifically?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel My only requirement is HomeKit compatibility. They’re just the cheapest I found. I just got the fan one installed and working. Still figuring out how to install the Smart Light one.

Comment: Do the devices themselves have an ETL in a circle near a 5-8 digit file number?   Or do they only say CE or CCC?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica When I was installing the second smart switch for the light I realized it was actually a 3 way switch. It controlled both my light and the outlet below the switch. I tied the third wire (controlling my light) to the line wire so it always has power so my smart switch now only controls the outlet. I added some automation in homekit so that pressing the switch also turns on and off my light. However, I have a new problem. Whenever I turn the light on or off using my app instead of the switch it offsets the switch, so that I have to turn it on and off again before it works

Comment: @Dan yeah, that's what happens when you try to force things to work without understanding what's going on.  It sounds like maybe you need to take a step back and do a full assessment of the circuit, and maybe ask more information here.  We can help if you give us info, photos and the like.  P.S. Remember: don't experiment.  There are lots of configurations that will work *and then kill you*.